# Duplicates while querying Three tables to get Common values using LINQ.

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two tables Orders,Automobiles relating to Customers table.While querying three tables i am getting duplicates Instead of single Value for each Customer.The resultant Query is a bit confusing for me,How would you deal with this kind of situations . I am using "ViewModel"=Model to Index,Create,Edit,Delete the Customer information.

```
 public class ProductVM
    {
        //Products
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Supplier_ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Product_Code { get; set; }

        //Specifications
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Bullet_Point { get; set; }
        public string Bullet_Point1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Product_ID { get; set; }


    }
```

Here is the Edit functions for the same.

```
         [HttpGet]     
public ActionResult Edit(int? id){
List<CustomerVM> CustomerVMlist = new List<CustomerVM>(); // to hold list of Customer and order details

var customerlist =(from Cust in db.Customers
                join Ord in db.Orders on Cust.CustomerID equals Ord.CustomerID
                 join auto in db.AutoMobiles on  Cust.CustomerID equals auto.CustomerID
                 where Cust.CustomerID==1
                 select new { Cust.Name, Cust.Mobileno, Cust.Address, Ord.OrderDate, Ord.OrderPrice,auto.Vehicle_Type}).ToList();

                    foreach (var item in customerlist) {
                        CustomerVM VMOBJ = new CustomerVM();
                        VMOBJ.Name= item.Name;
                        VMOBJ.Mobileno = item.Mobileno;
                        VMOBJ.Address = item.Address;
                        VMOBJ.OrderDate = item.OrderDate;
                        VMOBJ.OrderPrice = item.OrderPrice;
                        VMOBJ.Vehicle_Type = item.Vehicle_Type;
                        CustomerVMlist.Add(VMOBJ);
                    }

                    return View(CustomerVMlist);

                }
```

Comment: You're actually selecting one row per Order, not one row per customer.  You're even including fields from the Orders table in your results, so I'm not sure how you expect that to be one row per customer - it's logically impossible.

Comment: Do you have any example in Mind that shows proper Querying from three domain models. I have been struggling with the same. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

What is it you actually want to accomplish with this query?
The query you posted has 2 inner joins from Customer to Orders and from Customers to Automobiles. So when a Customer has placed two orders that customer will occur twice in the result. Sometimes it helps to first create the query with regular in SQL Management Studio for instance and then translate it to LINQ.

If you would want a list of all customers who have placed an order and want to add their last Order included in the result you could do this:

```
List<CustomerVM> customerList = (
    from cust in db.Customers

    let lastOrder = (
        from ord in db.Orders
        where ord.CustomerID == cust.CustomerID
        orderby ord.OrderDate descending
    ).FirstOrDefault()

    let automobile = (
        from auto in db.Automobiles
        where auto.CustomerID == cust.CustomerID
    ).FirstOrDefault()

    select new CustomerVM {
        Name = Cust.Name,
        Mobileno = Cust.Mobileno,
        Address = Cust.Address,
        OrderDate = lastOrder.OrderDate,
        OrderPrice = lastOrder.OrderPrice,
        Vehicle_Type = automobile.Vehicle_Type
    }
).Tolist();
return View(customerList);
```